# AWS API Gateway - How can I dynamically set a stage variable after hitting an endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an endpoint called "authorize" that I call. It returns a value named "accesstoken". I would like to store this value as a stage variable to be used in subsequent calls to additional endpoints on that stage.

Here's a clear example:

2 endpoints: "authorize" and "listEvents"

listEvents requires an accesstoken, which does not yet exist.

1) Call authorize and get back an accesstoken
2) Store accesstoken as a Stage Variable
3) Call listEvents, which uses the accesstoken Stage Variable to complete its call.

How would I do step 2 above?

Comment: Problem: "subsequent calls to additional endpoints" would not know whether the same client was making the request.  There is no state in HTTP. (Also, Stage Variables appear to be constants).

Comment: Okay, understood.  Ultimately, I just need a way to store variables in AWS instead of passing them back in the endpoint responses.  I want to call an endpoint, store the results of the call in AWS (somewhere) and be able to access those variables with future calls to other endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Stage variables can be stored using the API Gateway management API.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-stage.html